# Best Spring boot project structure with controller, service, entity and repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, microservices

Working on new project, it's a spring boot microservice application and I have a each controller, service and repository for each module like common, online and offline so I have created project structure as below,

1)

```
com.netbank.abc
               configuration
               entity
               constants
               utils
               common
                     controller
                     service
                     repository
               online
                     controller
                     service
                     repository
```

2. This is another approach kept entity also inside corresponding packages,

```
com.netbank.abc
               configuration
               constants
               utils
               common
                     controller
                     service
                     repository
                     entity
               online
                     controller
                     service
                     repository
                     entity
```

3. Created each layer with each module packages like below,

```
com.netbank.abc
               configuration
               entity
               constants
               utils
               controller
                         common
                         online
               service
                         common
                         online
               repository
                         common
                         online
```

Let me know which one need to go for project structure as I feel the first one looks fine as we have some common layer and with corresponding controller, service and repository folder.

Comment: If the entity is commonly used in common and online packages, number 1 seems appropriate, and if the entity is used separately for each package (eg, commonEntity, onlineEntity), number 2 seems appropriate.

When configuring a project package, I think the dependency direction of the package is important. This will be different for each project. Therefore, I think that Best Practice is Case By Case.

Comment: There is no right or wrong here, so structure it in the way that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: @lane.maxwell I am new to this framework so need input here. I understood there is no right or wrong based on the project need to choose the right one.

Comment: @soonhankwon entity is used commonly so first one is appropriate. Thank you

Comment: @AnilNivargi since these are microservices, I would extract the entities into their own library and create two separate services, common and online